# Export Data in Excel Sheet cells

Tags: excel, asp-classic

I am exporting the data in the excel sheet in classic asp. I am using the external table approach for export data in excel sheet.

I want to know is there any way to export the data into excel sheet cell. Because when I am using exported file for import I show me the error.

Regards & Thanks,

Jelly Saini

Comment: I think a straight forward answer is to make a csv file.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not exactly what you need, but this works:

```
<%
  Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  ExcelApp.Application.Visible = True
  ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False
  Set ExcelBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Add
  ExcelBook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Font.Size = 12
  ExcelBook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Font.Bold = True
  ExcelBook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value="Hello"
  ExcelBook.SaveAs Server.MapPath(".") & "\Hello.xls"
  ExcelApp.Application.Quit
  Set ExcelApp = Nothing
%>
```